# ROS Answers SE migration: bag to csv

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am doing this to grab a topic from my bag
rostopic echo -p -b bagfile.bag /topic1 > topic1.txt

an example text file is this:

%time,field.axes0

1319232665843818430,0.0

1319232665893904494,0.0

is %time unix time? because I can't seem to convert it.

What I would like is to convert this to tell me the number of seconds from its start, so the bag starts with 0 time, this is to match the timestamp on an audiofile logged at the same time as this.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11990/bag-to-csv/) by [deathside](https://answers.ros.org/users/1405/deathside/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-11-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2011-11-22**:
Seems like its the unix time at nanosecond level. You could trim of the last 9 digits if you dont care for sub-second accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's probably the easiest to use the Python API of rosbag. [See this example](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Cookbook#Rewrite_bag_with_header_timestamps) for how to access the timestamp and [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy/Overview/Time) is a description for handling times with rospy.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-12-01**:
Have you tried to use the tip of Ben_S in the comment on your question?

**Comment by [deathside](https://answers.ros.org/users/1405/deathside/) on 2011-11-28**:
I did the reindex. Still getting the same error. Please help

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-11-23**:
rosbag (the command line tool) has a reindex function, see "rosbag help"

**Comment by [deathside](https://answers.ros.org/users/1405/deathside/) on 2011-11-22**:
I am trying the cookbook python example and I am getting this... rosbag.bag.ROSBagUnindexedException: Unindexed bag